# Unable to download a file from baidu website

Tags: download, file-download

I am trying to download this file on my mac

https://pan.baidu.com/s/1bhJbsGSD7bXf4txmsqaplA

I have managed to create a baidu account from here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Piracy/comments/auhyxk/how_do_i_download_from_panbaidu/eovyg8g?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x

The website tells me to install a download manager, which I am not able to. I posted this on stack overflow but was asked to repost it here.

Comment: Unless you install the download manager, it probably isn't even possible to (potentially) discover the URL the file is being downloaded from.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was using a mac and there was some problem with the downloader. Worked on Windows.

Comment: Good to hear. =)